# How to make "terraform plan" use my config file

Tags: azure, terraform

1. I created an Azure service principal
2. I created a file called **azureProviderAndCreds.tf** that looks similar to the following:

   ```
   variable subscription_id {}
   variable tenant_id {}
   variable client_id {}
   variable client_secret {}

   provider "azurerm" {
       subscription_id = "<my-azure-subscription-id>"
       tenant_id = "<tenantid-returned-from-creating-a-service-principal>"
       client_id = "<appid-returned-from-creating-a-service-principal>"
      client_secret = "<password-returned-from-creating-a-service-principal>"
   }
   ```
3. I ran **terraform init**
4. I ran **terraform plan**

When executing **terraform plan**, the command asks me for the **client_id**.

I have this value defined in the **azureProviderAndCreds.tf** file. How do I get Terraform to look at my config file for that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd read through the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html) to get a handle of the input variables basics.

But heres a couple quick things:

You are declaring variables and not actually using them in your provider:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"
  tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"
  client_id       = "${var.client_id}"
  client_secret   = "${client_secret}"
}
```

You could set defaults for your variables when declaring them:

```
variable subscription_id {
  default = "your-subscription-id"
}
```

Of you could create a `.tfvars` file like `variables.tfvars` and pass that when running plan:

```
subscription_id = "your-subscription-id"
tenant_id = "your-tenant-id"
client_id = "your-client-id"
client_secret = "your-client-secret"

terraform plan -var-file=variables.tfvars
```

Comment: Using the variables file worked perfectly. As an FYI, if the Terraform variables file is named "terraform.tfvars" or follows the pattern "*.auto.tfvars", the "terraform plan" command will pick it up automatically and the "-var-file" parameter isn't needed.